# Facebook User sends invitation to a fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way that a user can invite his/her friends to a fanpage similar the Facebook request dialog?

I'm looking for a solution where someone can open a popup and select her/his friend with mulit-friend-selector and store the userid´s from user inviting and recipient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Facebook Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) "friend multi-selector" only forwards users to the App's Canvas page on Facebook (a Tab is not technically "the Canvas Page"). It is geared towards games and such which run in the Canvas. From the documentation:

> Note: Requests are only available for Canvas apps and not websites. Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

That said, you can re-purpose it for your own use with a little trickery. Basically, you need to set up a redirect on the Canvas page that forwards users to your Facebook Page ("fanpage"). This article explains one way to do that (which I have used):

http://af-design.com/blog/2011/02/17/using-facebook-requests-to-promote-a-website/

**Edit:** Just to clarify a little more, with this solution you will now have two pages / "bits of code":

1. The "Invite Friends" page where you call the multi-select Request Dialog. (Perhaps you are putting this in the App's Tab iframe?)
2. The Canvas page (you're Apps iframe URL) which invited friends ("Invitees") will land on after they accept the invite.

Page 2) is where you need to place the redirect() code which sends them back to your "fanpage". The friend request will always send the "Invitee" to the Canvas page (2). Once they are there, you need to redirect them with something like this:

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/MYFANPAGE'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks so far but this redirects me again to the canvas app - site.

Comment: I added a little more info, I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: ok, thanks therefore!! I tried the redirectings but it only told me that "This content cannot be shown in an frame". The second thing is how can I print the results of the invitation?

Comment: I added the following code for redirecting wich works: `echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $page_tab_url . "'</script>");`